# Save datasets with different names in for loop in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, dataset

I am trying to implement the following:

```
dataset_id_1 = subset(data, id == 1)
dataset_id_2 = subset(data, id == 2)
dataset_id_3 = subset(data, id == 3)
```

However, I need to do this for more than 100 IDs. I encounter a problem in generating the name of the dataset on the left. I tried the following:

```
for (i in 1:120) {
  dataset_id_[[i]] = subset(data, id == i)
}
```

Do you know how to save the name of the dataset according to the specified id?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#List
List <- list()
#Loop
for (i in 1:120) {
  List[[i]] = subset(data, id == i)
}
#Names
names(List) <- paste0('dataset_id_',1:length(List))
#Set to envir
list2env(List,envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: @TheCodeBanker Always a pleasure helping, and remember that is better storing data in lists and then process to dataframes. Kind regards!

Answer (score 0):

Try `split` + `list2env` like below

```
lst <- split(volping, volping$id)
list2env(setNames(lst,paste0("dataset_id_",names(lst))), .GlobalEnv)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```r
for (i in 1:120) {
  assign(paste("dataset_id_", i),  subset(data, id == i) ) 
}
```